# asp.net email fails on server when file attached

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, attachment

The email goes suceessfully when I send it from localhost and use an external smtp settings, but email never goes when I run the code on live server and email has attachment. In web.config I have:

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
            <network host="localhost" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

This problem only arises on live site with email attachment. It works fine on localhost with or without attachment.

Comment: is the attachment a file that already exists or are you making it within your application?

Comment: I'm attaching using file upload control

Comment: My guess is that you're having a permissions issue on the server that you can't read the file that's why you can't attach it.  Is your identity impersonate tag on?

Comment: I've tried this turning on but in vain

Comment: @hotcoder, issue can be permission related or SMTP related (e.g. what if your SMTP does not allow attachment with certain size etc). I will suggest that you build a small window/console test app to send an email using same code and test it on live server. If it fails, display/log exception trail; if it succeeds then you can be assured that issue is related to user permissions.

Comment: This is a bad question. Where is the error message, so we don't have to guess wildly from the 10+ potential points of failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code helped me:

```
 Dim client As New SmtpClient()
    client.Host = "relay.neural.net.au"
    Try
        client.Send(mailMsg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it could be a problem with your web.config settings. Did you have something like:

```
  <location path="email" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" maxRequestLength="15360" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

If your aspx file is under a dir named "email".